# Which racing game is it?

Tags: game-identification, windows

This is a old PC racing game. Can anybody please remind me what is the name of this game?

[image]

Comment: 4 years ain't that old... or am I getting old? :(

Comment: @Mixxiphoid maybe he meant that's a racing game on an old PC. Right? Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The game is [Need For Speed: Payback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Need_for_Speed_Payback).

You can find a related gameplay video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4484xdymZOo).